# Date Range Formula

Tags: crystal-reports, parameters

**Page1:**

From Date: TXTBOX1   To Date: TXTBOX2

BTNSUBMIT-CLICK
{
server.transfer("page2.aspx");
}

**Page 2:**

if (PreviousPage != null)
        {
            TextBox txt1 = PreviousPage.FindControl("TXTBOX1") as TextBox;
            TextBox txt2 = PreviousPage.FindControl("TXTBOX2") as TextBox;

```
        if (txt1.Text.Length != 0 && txt2.Text.Length != 0)
        {

         ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
         cryRpt.Load("MyReport.rpt");

            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new         
            ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = txt1.Text + txt2.Text;
            crParameterFieldDefinitions =
            cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition =
            crParameterFieldDefinitions["MyParameter"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;

        }

     }
```

Formula In Formula Editor:

{Command.Date} >= {?MyParameter} and {Command.Date} <= {?MyParameter}

It works fine If report is displayed for single date. Not for Date Range.

Any Suggestions? Where i am wrong in formula / code ???

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the date fields as separate parameters, and reference them in your Formula Editor like this:

```
{Command.Date} >= {?ParamDateFrom} and {Command.Date} <= {?ParamDateTo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ParameterRangeValue instead of a ParameterDiscreteValue, and set the StartValue and EndValue properties to your start and end dates.

Update: 
Here's some sample code that worked on a test report:

```
     ParameterFieldDefinitions paramDefinitions =  report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;

     ParameterFieldDefinition paramDefinition = paramDefinitions["DateRange"];
     ParameterValues paramValues = paramDefinition.CurrentValues;

     ParameterRangeValue rangeValue = new ParameterRangeValue();
     rangeValue.StartValue = new DateTime(2010, 10, 31);
     rangeValue.EndValue = new DateTime(2010, 12, 15);

     paramValues.Add(rangeValue); ;

     paramDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(paramValues);
```

Make sure that your `MyParameter` is a range value, and that the select statement in Crystal is `dateField = {?MyParameter}`